# C# WYSIWYG Web Field by Drag and Drop

Tags: c#, html, drag-and-drop, wysiwyg

I would like to know what type of field is used for a WebEditor (like WebBuilder) to Drag-and-Drop text, input,... in C# ?

I thinking of an HTML field, but not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean Web based application, you should take a look at ASP.NET WebForms. If you want to build desktop application, Visual Studio has a project template called Windows Form Application consisting drag drop support. I don't recommend you using Web Form for web-based application, rather use ASP.NET MVC framework for this purpose which does not include drag-drop functionality in development.

Comment: Thank you, it's a desktop application. I think a Form in a MDI Form is a solution. Thank you very much.